# DataFrame.apply() to column with list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am drawing a blank on how to do this properly, I have a dataframe containing bounding box coordinates as a `list` type.
ex:

```
                  bb_box
0    [4, 565, 1088, 591]
1   [17, 820, 1092, 949]
2    [5, 746, 1084, 796]
3   [32, 240, 1104, 263]
4    [0, 187, 1111, 212]
...
```

I need to apply normalization coordinates to each value in the list of the `bb_box` column. I want to use a vectorized approach to this by applying the following function:

Rough code outline:

```
def align_coordinates(align_coord, box):
    """ align_coordinates
        align_coord    A list of 4 values to add to the box coordinates
        box            The box coordinates that need to be aligned 
    """
    for idx, v in enumerate(align_coord):
        box[idx] = box[idx] + v

    return box

offset_coords = [10,10,10,10]
df['bb_box'] = np.vectorize(align_coordinates)(offset_coords, df['bb_box'])
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (5,)
```

I think its because I have a list of 4x values that I am trying to apply to a column of 5 rows with a list of 4 values in each row.

Is there a better approach to do this? How do I apply a constant list of offset values to the dataframe column?

Edit 1:
This is my current approach, not using any "vectorization":

```
offset_coords = [10,10,10,10]
for i, v in df.iterrows():
    r_box = df.at[i,'bb_box']
    r_box = np.add(r_box, offset_coords)
    df.at[i,'bb_box'] = r_box
```

Comment: You cannot vectorize this. Once you store a list in a column, everything that appears to be "vectorised" will just drop down into a python `for` loop

Comment: See the notes on [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). You're not going to gain any performance from this; all you've done is add overhead from `pandas`. You'd be better with a python structure if you want to keep going this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to vectorize, convert to numpy array:

```
offset_coords = [10,10,10,10]

df['bb_box2'] = (np.array(df['bb_box'].to_list()) + offset_coords).tolist()
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
df['bb_box2'] = [[sum(x) for x in zip(l, offset_coords)] for l in df['bb_box']]
```

Output:

```
                 bb_box               bb_box2
0   [4, 565, 1088, 591]  [14, 575, 1098, 601]
1  [17, 820, 1092, 949]  [27, 830, 1102, 959]
2   [5, 746, 1084, 796]  [15, 756, 1094, 806]
3  [32, 240, 1104, 263]  [42, 250, 1114, 273]
4   [0, 187, 1111, 212]  [10, 197, 1121, 222]
```

##### timings

on 500k rows

```
# numpy version
391 ms ± 30.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# list comprehension
493 ms ± 32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @roganjosh I have tested it and it does work (Series has both the `tolist` and `to_list` methods) ;)

Comment: @roganjosh I added some timings, using numpy is faster. If you have a better approach I'd be thrilled to see it :)

Comment: I'm not saying I do, but surely the bbox can be sub-divided pretty successfully into 4 columns of scalars and something could be done there? I didn't realise there was `to_list()` and `tolist()` (loving the API here) but it must be dropping into Python-time in this case vs. any proper vectorization?

Comment: Well pandas API names are pretty clean, numpy's one not so much. I guess pandas has `to_list` as a "clean name" and `tolist` to help users familiar with numpy. Anyway using lists in a Series is not a good idea in the first place, I believe the above approach is the best you can get.

Comment: Heh, I'd argue it was the other way around about API cleanliness :P But perhaps an approach would be to explode that list out into columns and try do this?

Comment: Currently I drop into a `.iterrows()` and then `numpy.add()` to add the two lists together. Have not done a performance check but I am assuming its bad. I can definitely divide the list inter separate scalar columns... personally I just thought that looked ugly. What would be the performance advantage of going that rout?

Comment: @Zexelon I don't understand your question, what are you trying to do with `iterrows`?

Comment: @mozway I am iterating over the rows in `bb_box` and individually updating them. I will update my question with my current approach.

Comment: @Zexelon you should probably open a new question, this looks like a different problem